# Database assignment with MySQL and Swing

Tags: java, database, homework, swing

I have completed [this assignment from Stanford CS108](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs108/handouts141/20HW3DBSudoku.pdf) on MySQL and Swing (it's part B). It would be wonderful if someone could point out my weak spots in the code and overall design.

I have uploaded code on [GitHub.](https://github.com/AndrewBaliushin/Stanford-CS108-Object-Oriented-System-Design/tree/master/HW3Sudoku/hw3DBSudoku/src/databaseexercise)

#### Task:

> In this part of the assignment you will create a GUI-based (Graphical
>   User Interface) application which will allow a user to access the
>   example metropolises database from the Database handout.
>
> The application will provide options allowing the user to either
>   search for metropolises matching particular criteria or to add a new
>   metropolis to the database. The application should include a JTable
>   which displays information gathered from the metropolises database.
>
> [image]

I ended up with this:

[image]

#### JMetropolisViewer.java

```
package databaseexercise;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JMetropolisViewer extends JFrame {

    public static final String APP_TITLE = "Metropolis Viewer";
    public static final String METROPOLIS = "Metropolis";
    public static final String POPULATION = "Population";
    public static final String CONTINENT = "Continent";

    //index[0] must be "larger than"
    private static final String[] optionsForPopulation = {"Population larger than", "Population less than"};
    //index[0] must be "partial match" 
    private static final String[] optionsForMatch = {"Partial match", "Exact match"};

    private List<City> metropolisList = new ArrayList<City>();
    private Database db;
    private MetropolisTableModel tableModel;

    private JTextField cityNameInput;
    private JTextField continentInput;
    private JTextField populationInput;

    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton searchButton;

    private JComboBox<String> populationSearchOptions;
    private JComboBox<String> matchSearchOptions;

    public JMetropolisViewer() {
        super(APP_TITLE);

        db = new Database(metropolisList);
        db.readAll();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        add(makeInputFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tableModel = new MetropolisTableModel(metropolisList);
        add(makeResultTable(tableModel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addListners();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ignored) { }

        JMetropolisViewer metropolisViewer = new JMetropolisViewer();   

    }

    private JPanel makeInputFieldsPanel() {
        JPanel inputFieldsPanel = new JPanel();
        inputFieldsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel cityL = new JLabel(METROPOLIS + ":");
        inputFieldsPanel.add(cityL);
        cityNameInput = new JTextField(10);
        inputFieldsPanel.add(cityNameInput);

        JLabel contL = new JLabel(CONTINENT + ":");
        inputFieldsPanel.add(contL);
        continentInput = new JTextField(10);
        inputFieldsPanel.add(continentInput);

        JLabel populationL = new JLabel(POPULATION + ":");
        inputFieldsPanel.add(populationL);
        populationInput = new JTextField(10);
        inputFieldsPanel.add(populationInput);

        inputFieldsPanel.add(makeControlPanel());

        return inputFieldsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel makeControlPanel() {
        JPanel contolPanel = new JPanel();
        contolPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contolPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        contolPanel.add(addButton);

        searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        contolPanel.add(searchButton);

        contolPanel.add(makeSearchOptionBox());

        return contolPanel;
    }

    private JPanel makeSearchOptionBox() {
        JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();
        optionsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(optionsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        optionsPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Search options"));

        populationSearchOptions = new JComboBox<String>(optionsForPopulation);
        populationSearchOptions.setSelectedIndex(0);
        optionsPanel.add(populationSearchOptions);


        matchSearchOptions = new JComboBox<String>(optionsForMatch);
        matchSearchOptions.setSelectedIndex(0);
        optionsPanel.add(matchSearchOptions);

        return optionsPanel;        
    }

    private JScrollPane makeResultTable(AbstractTableModel model) {
        JTable resultTable = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultTable);

        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void addListners() {
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    db.add(createCity());
                    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    db.search(cityNameInput.getText(),
                            continentInput.getText(),
                            parsePopulationInput(),
                            (matchSearchOptions.getSelectedIndex() == 0),
                            (populationSearchOptions.getSelectedIndex() == 0));
                    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private City createCity() {
        String city = cityNameInput.getText();
        String continent = continentInput.getText();
        int population = parsePopulationInput();
        if (city.length() != 0 && continent.length() != 0) {
            return new City(city,continent, population);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private int parsePopulationInput() {
        String input = populationInput.getText();
        if(input.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Database.java

```
package databaseexercise;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Database {

    private static final String METROPOLIS_FIELD = MyDBInfo.METROPOLIS_FIELD;
    private static final String CONTINENT_FIELD = MyDBInfo.CONTINENT_FIELD;
    private static final String POPULATION_FIELD = MyDBInfo.POPULATION_FIELD;

    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    private List<City> citiesList;

    public Database(List<City> citiesList) {
        this.citiesList = citiesList;
    }

    private void readDataBase(String SQL) throws SQLException {
        try {
          connect();
          statement = connection.createStatement();
          resultSet = statement
              .executeQuery(SQL);

          citiesList.clear();

          while (resultSet.next())
          {
             citiesList.add(new City(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getInt(3)));
          } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.err.println("SQL: " + SQL);
        } finally {
          connection.close();
        }

      }

    public void readAll() {
        try {
            readDataBase("SELECT * FROM " + MyDBInfo.TABLE_NAME);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void search(String city, String continent, int population, boolean partialMatch,
            boolean popLargerThan) {
        if (city.length() == 0 && continent.length() ==0 && population == 0) {
            readAll();
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder sbSql = new StringBuilder();

        sbSql.append("SELECT * FROM ");
        sbSql.append(MyDBInfo.TABLE_NAME);
        sbSql.append(" WHERE ");

        List<String> whereStatments = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (city.length() > 0 && partialMatch) {
            whereStatments.add(METROPOLIS_FIELD + " LIKE '%" + city + "%'");
        } else if (city.length() > 0) {
            whereStatments.add(METROPOLIS_FIELD + " = '" + city + "'");
        }

        if (continent.length() > 0 && partialMatch) {
            whereStatments.add(CONTINENT_FIELD + " LIKE '%" + continent + "%'");
        } else if (continent.length() > 0) {
            whereStatments.add(CONTINENT_FIELD + " = '" + continent + "'");
        }

        if (population != 0 && popLargerThan) {
            whereStatments.add(POPULATION_FIELD + " > " + population);
        } else if (population != 0) {
            whereStatments.add(POPULATION_FIELD + " < " + population);
        }

        Iterator<String> iter = whereStatments.iterator();
        boolean first = true;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (!first) {
                sbSql.append(" AND ");
            } else {
                first = false;
            }
            sbSql.append(iter.next());          
        }


        try {
            readDataBase(sbSql.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL: " + sbSql.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add(City city) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + MyDBInfo.TABLE_NAME
                + " (" + METROPOLIS_FIELD +" , " + CONTINENT_FIELD + ", "
                + POPULATION_FIELD + ") " + "VALUES (?, ? , ?)";

        if (city == null) {
            System.out.println("City is null");
            return;
        }

        try {
            connect();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, city.getCityName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, city.getCityContinent());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, city.getPopulation());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            citiesList.add(city);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

    }

    private void connect() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.
                  getConnection(MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_SERVER + MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME,
                  MyDBInfo.MYSQL_USERNAME, MyDBInfo.MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

#### MetropolisTableModel.java

```
package databaseexercise;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MetropolisTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<City> cityList;

    MetropolisTableModel(List<City> cityList) {
        this.cityList = cityList;
    }

    private String[] colNames = {JMetropolisViewer.METROPOLIS,
            JMetropolisViewer.CONTINENT, JMetropolisViewer.POPULATION};

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return colNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return cityList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        if(row < 0 || row >= cityList.size()) return null;
        City obj = cityList.get(row);
        switch(column)
        {
            case 0: return obj.getCityName();
            case 1: return obj.getCityContinent();
            case 2: return obj.getPopulation();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

#### City.java

```
package databaseexercise;

public class City {
    private String cityName;
    private String cityContinent;
    private int population;

    public City(String cityName, String cityContinent, int population) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.cityContinent = cityContinent;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
    public String getCityContinent() {
        return cityContinent;
    }
    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`getValueAt`: Bounds check**

`if(row < 0 || row >= cityList.size()) return null;` doesn't seem right to me. Here is how the `DefaultTableModel` handles it:

```
/**
 * [...]
 *
 * @exception  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  if an invalid row or
 *               column was given
 */
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Vector rowVector = (Vector)dataVector.elementAt(row);
    return rowVector.elementAt(column);
}
```

I think throwing a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` seems like a good idea. Alternatively, you could also store default values somewhere and return those (eg "missing", "n/a", "", "invalid column", etc).

**Misc**

- You print quite a lot in your classes. Try to handle this via return values or exceptions instead.
- In your finally block, you should check if `connection` is null before closing it.
- variables should have as small a scope as possible. For example, `preparedStatement` doesn't need to be at class level.
- you use prepared statements in `add`, why not use them in `search` as well.
- try not to throw or catch the generic `Exception`, but all the specific exceptions, so that the calling method can handle each as it wants to.

Answer (score 2):

Code is well formatted and good style.

One thing I would avoid using is `import *` and import the packages you actually need. The latter is better practice, because it avoids import conflicts.